# Regex to find lines containing sequence but not containing a different sequence

Tags: regex, string, search, notepad++

How do I write a regular expression to find all lines containing 665 and not having .pdf

I can't seem to find how to do not in regex.  This is for Notepad++ syntax if it matters.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `.pdf` will only occur after `665`, the negative lookahead assertion `665(?!.*\.pdf)` should work fine. Otherwise, I prefer to use two regexs, one to match, one to fail. In Perl syntax that would be:

```
/665/ && !/\.pdf/
```

Answer (score 2):

The feature you'r looking for is look ahead patterns

```
665(?!.*\.pdf)
```

Comment: That won't work if the ".pdf" precedes the "665" (which may or may not matter to the original poster).